# Installing Flutter 3 build on Android 12 is showing an error message - There was a problem parsing the package. How to fix this issue?

Tags: android, flutter, apk, android-manifest

Getting the runtime issue as shown in the screenshot, while installing the Flutter 3 build in Android 12 and above. I tried to add **android:exported="true"** in all the activities in the app manifest, but still facing the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to fix the Issue:**

1. Open the merged manifest in an editor -
   `<project>/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests`
2. Check if all the tags - activities, services, and receivers have **android:exported="true/false"** attribute
3. Open the app manifest and add the **exported** attribute to above the manifest tags.
4. Check the diff between the merged manifest and the app main manifest. If you find any tags from any plugins in the merged manifest with no **exported** attribute, add those tags to the app main manifest as shown below -

```
<activity
    android:name="com.wongpiwat.trust_location.TrustLocationPlugin"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:node="merge" />
```